# How to import Bash functions with the following naming convention: "[module]::[function name]"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a collection of functions in a .sh file called library.sh .

I was hoping to define each function in my library to create a pseudo name space as follows:

```
library::functionA () 
{
...
}

library::functionB() 
{
...
}
```

And then in the main script call the library functions as follows:

```
. lib/library.sh
...
library::functionA
```

When I run the main script, I get an error message:

```
library::functionA command not found
```

There is an example here in the rerun project: 
https://github.com/rerun/rerun/blob/master/etc/bash_completion.sh
(see list:member) 
 but the method is called locally and only has one colon.

The idea is also mentionned in Google's shell style link: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml

> under function names ..  Separate libraries with ::. Parentheses are
>   required after the function name.

I would like to have [module name]::[function name]. 
What am I missing? 
Thanks for your help,

Comment: That should work. Wildly guessing: Are you trying to run the function in a subshell, for example as part of a command substitution?

Comment: For now no. Let's say I have a function defined in my library.sh: library::test() { local _var=$1; echo "in test function; $_var;" } . In my main script I call the test function: library::test("this is a test:1235456"). I get "syntax error near unexpected token `"this is a test:123456"' .. line x:  `library::test("this is a test:123456")'. Should I be running this in a subshell?

Comment: No, but if you had run it in a subshell, that would explain why it isn't found and could be fixed with `typeset -fx functionname` (that is essentially `export` for functions). My other guess is that you used a `#!/bin/sh` shebang instead of `#!/bin/bash`, in which case changing that should fix it. I think POSIX shell has a problem with colons in function names. EDIT: Yeah, `dash` doesn't like them, for example.

Comment: @Alain: You can't use parentheses to call a bash function with parameters. The syntax error comes because after `name(` the only legal token is ')', indicating the beginning of a function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that. Thanks rici. I made it work by removing the parantheses and adding a specific instruction typeset -fx library::test to the method I wanted to export in the library.sh. Plus one to you both. but isn't there a better way to export all functions from a script? fyi, typeset seems to be obsolete.

The answer to my question is: typeset -f on top of the library.sh. Sweet, this is very cool! thanks! All functions exported.

If I call a local method now inside my library, I need to add "library::". Is there a bash built-in instruction to say if the function is local omit the label "library::" ?